# Child groups with all parents disabled shows in group list

Tags: contacts, groups

I'am currently using Civicrm version 5.3.1 with drupal 7.59.
Steps to replicate:

1. Create one group, parent A.
2. Create a one group, child A and assign parent A group created above as 
   parent.
3. Disable parent A group.
4. Go to contacts->manage groups. You are unable to see both parent and child groups.
5. Click on any search criteria. Unclick it. You can see the `child A` group with title as `Child A Child of:`. With null value for parent

**How it works currently:** If a child group has multiple parent groups and one of them is disabled, the child group should to show up on group selector lists. This has been fixed here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20934.

If all parent group(s) are disabled the child group still shows up in search mode.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Shouldn't the child group be removed from the selector lists if all parent group(s) are disabled?

Comment: This site is more for questions and answers, not for bug reports, I'm editing the question to be more "question" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could still have contacts assigned to a (enabled) child group, so I don't find it very surprising you can use it on search.

More generally, what enabled/disabled means in the context of group hierarchy is probably not fully clear, and it's likely that different users expect different things, and it's especially true with multiple hierarchical relationships.

Wouldn't it be easier you disable the child groups when you disable the parent (assuming it's not happening too often)?

Comment: Thanks !
Agreed with your thoughts. But I think even if we have child groups enabled and all parent(s) disabled 
it should not show child group in search right? 
Other solution for this may be we can disable all child group while disableing parents group as its not possible to 
manually disable all the child groups due to major numbers. 
​
According to that we can add issue on Jira and provide some patch. Thoughts?

Comment: HI, could you start by creating an issue, so we can see if there is a consensus on what should be the "more correct" approach? I haven't used enough group hierarchy+disable in the sites I've installed to have an informed opinion, but some might ;)

Comment: Thanks :) Created issue here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/287